# Import and call identical function from all modules in the same directory

Tags: python, function, import, python-import

I have `def myfunc()` in `script2.py`, `script3.py`, `script4.py`. In `script1.py`, I want to call `myfunc` from script2, script3 and script 4.

In `script1.py`, rather than tediously listing out:

```
from script2.py import myfunc 
myfunc()
from script3.py import myfunc 
myfunc()
from script4.py import myfunc 
myfunc()
```

Is there a way that I can import `myfunc` from all scripts present in that same directory?

Comment: Umm... why not just `import scriptN` then access with `scriptN.myfunc`?

Comment: Do you mean just changing the numbers (2,3,4) of the filenames to `N`? How about if my files were not sharing common prefixes in their name?

Comment: I'm sure that Mateen means that you should have a series of `import scriptN` statements, then you can access each `myfunc` by using a longer name in each case, eg: `scriptN.myfunc()`.

Comment: @quamrana: So that means doing: `import script2, script3, script4` and then `scriptN.myfunc()`?

Comment: Well, no, if you do `import script2, script3, script4`, then you will need to call `script2.myfunc()` or `script3.myfunc()` etc.

Comment: Ok, got it. So this method does shortens things abit. But I will still have to call the function for each of the imported modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are probably searching for is dynamic import

you can use the `__import__` function to call your functions in a loop

```
for i in range(2, 5):
    try:
        script_module = __import__("script{}.py".format(i))
        script_module.myfunc()
    except ImportError:
        pass # or do whatever when this fails...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What if my files have different names i.e. no common prefixes. The only common thing is that they reside in the same folder (other than the fact that they have the identical function of interest). Is there a way to call the function from all these files with dissimilar names?

Comment: sure, just loop over their names, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory for how to list a directory

Comment: Just tried this method, works really well. Thanks! However, maybe it will be better to remove the `.py` as importing python files wouldn't require the `.py` extension to be written.

Comment: I added the .py extension as it was in the question, you could have file.py.py , no way to know so I try only to answer the question and not do a code review... we have https://codereview.stackexchange.com for that